# javascript confirm dialog box before close browser window

Tags: javascript

I need to display a confirm dialog box before closing the browser window using javascript or PHP. The confirm box should come up when I click the close button of browser; otherwise, the dialog should not be displayed.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prompt User before browser close?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923139/prompt-user-before-browser-close)

Comment: Please try searching SO before you ask a question. This question is answered several times. Try searching for *[javascript] dialog before close*

Answer (score 12):

This will display it when closing the browser:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
  var message = 'Sure you want to leave?';
  if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
    event = window.event;
  }
  if (event) {
    event.returnValue = message;
  }
  return message;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this code , I used that earlier, I [here](http://www.corecoding.com/browser-window-close-confirm_c23.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>.:I 0wn U:.</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
window.onbeforeunload = bunload;

function bunload(){
dontleave="Are you sure you want to leave?";
return dontleave;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
Please stay on this page!
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

With Jquery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e) {
    // Your code and validation
    if (confirm) {
        return "Are you sure?";
    }
});
```

Comment: this is the only thing that worked for me. using Angular8