# Javascript window close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get a custom alert box when user clicks on 'X' (window close).

- User is given 'OK' and 'Cancel' button options
- OK button closes the window. Cancel button cancels the close action

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript To Get An Alert When Closing The Browser Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333665/javascript-to-get-an-alert-when-closing-the-browser-window)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may find your answer on this post which looks similar - [javascript confirm dialog box before close browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966319/javascript-confirm-dialog-box-before-close-browser-window)

You have to show what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

**Html code**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return "Did you save your stuff?"
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ritesh,

If I do this, I got an alert from a web page. But I need a custom alert box with 'Ok','Cancel' butons.

Comment: A custom alert does not add anything