# Display alert message defore closing a popup window

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a popup with a yes or no question (radiobuttons) in it. I want to force the users of my site to select either one of the options before closing the popup, but i am not able to do so. I can simple close the popup using the 'RED' cross button on the popup.

Can anyone tell me how can i stop the users from navigating from this page? Is there a way to display a alert message and ask them to choose an option?

I am using C#.net, asp.net and JavaScript.

Comment: Please read the FAQ. This question is impossible to answer without code.

Comment: Might be useful to post a code fragment. Tell us what kind of popup you are using? JQuery? Custom made? Standard javascript? Little more explanation could provide you a lot of good answers.

Comment: You're going to have a really hard time preventing users from navigating away from your page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prompt User before browser close?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923139/prompt-user-before-browser-close)

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% way to hold the user of your site... You could show a selfmade popup something like this

```
#popupBox { 
    position: fixed;  
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;  
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4); 
}

#popup {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    left: 50%,
    margin-left: -130px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
}

<div id='popupBox'> 
    <div id='popup'>
        <button type='input' value='yes'>
        <button type='input' value='no'>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the insert of your popup ho have to reload the needed javascript for handel the click to one of this buttons...