# JavaScript: How can I prompts a custom message box when they close broswer?

Tags: javascript

**Problem:**

I am new in JavaScript. And I want to give a message like "you have down xxx works today!",
when my users close broswer. I've search google/stackoverflow and get some solutions in
[Prompt User before browser close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923139/prompt-user-before-browser-close)

BUT, when I try code as followd, it just shows the broswer's default message, not mine. How can I solve it?

**Code:**

```js
function test(evt) {
    var message = 'Did you remember to download your form?';
    if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
        evt = window.event;
    }
    if (evt) {
        evt.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
}
```

Are there some useful APIs or solutions for me?

**Edit (2021.9.22)**
I try the tips posted By @NiceBooks like

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    window.alert("ready to exit");
    window.confirm("just a test");
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

IE and FireFox prompt their default message. If e.returnValue is not set, there is no prompt box when I click exit button. [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) says:

'In some browsers, calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() may be ignored during this event. See the HTML specification for more details. '

Maybe it's the reason why I failed. But is there really no solution?

Comment: Do you want to use a browser prompt, alert or modal to display your message?

Comment: Yes, it's what i want @AnnFrancis Do you have any solution? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, most modern Browsers do not support custom messages. I had the same issue too. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: I have learnt this from stackoverflow and doc in MDN. But if I just want to prompt a confirm or alert dialog box befor user exit browser, is there any solution? Isn't there a way to prompt a custom message before the user click exit button？ @AnnFrancis

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to display a custom message in the beforeunload popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup)

Comment: @dueToLife If you're designing your own "close button", then yes. You can always do anything when the user is clicking your button. But if it's the system close button like you're closing the browser, then it triggers that event `beforeunload`, then event `unload`, then you can't do anything.

Comment: @dueToLife If you have an exit button, then you can display a modal or alert with your message when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thank you @CasimirCrystal . I have tried some method in above link. But now they are useless. I've already understand why my efforts failed. Again, Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @AnnFrancis . I've understanded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `window.confirm(msg)` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Use it in conjunction with the `beforeunload` event on the `window` object:

[beforeunload in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: I have tried your advice like '<body onbeforeunload="window.confirm('just a test')">'. But when i click the exit button, there is nothing happend....

Comment: Use beforeunload with window not body. See edit.

Comment: Thank you @NiceBooks I read both docs and make some attempt. It still doesn't work but I get some information. I edit it in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, enter the following code inside the `head` tag.

```
<script>
const beforeUnloadListener = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  return event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
};

//this piece of code will trigger a pupup message
addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadListener, {capture: true});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.